# How can i change Portrait Mode to Landscape Mode on button click?

Tags: swift

For e.g my FirstVC is in Portrait.When I click on button SecondVC is appear, I want to display SecondVC in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

This code is working fine for me.